# ssh to the same server of openvpn, tries to connect with original IP instead of VPN IP

Tags: ssh, openvpn, ufw

I'm using ubuntu Linux 22.04.3 LTS with OpenVPN 2.5.5 and i have ssh server installed there too.

i want people to be able to connect to that server by ssh only if they are connected to the VPN.

that server has a ufw firewall and i allowed both the wan ip of the vpn and the openvpn subnet to port 22 but it doesn't work.

when I check my ufw log to see why he blocked it, it's because it detected the origination ip is my actual wan ip, it's not the wan ip of the VPN or the subnet of the openvpn configuration, besides that the vpn works great, what am I missing ?

this is my openvpn server configuration:

```
local 0.0.0.0
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert foofoo.crt
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
compress lz4-v2
push "compress lz4-v2"
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
push "redirect-gateway def1"
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/crl.pem
```

and this is my client configuration (besides the keys):

```
cipher AES-256-CBC
client
nobind
remote <VPN_WAN_IP> 1194 udp
dev tun
proto udp
dev-type tun
verb 3
persist-key
persist-tun
resolv-retry infinite
auth-nocache
remote-cert-tls server
compress lz4-v2
```

thank you.

Comment: What's the command you use for SSH? The answer is probably that you're attempting to connect to the public IP, and not the VPN IP, so the connection is not routed over the VPN connection.